# Redirect https://www.subdomain.domain.com/ to https://subdomain.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect https://www.subdomain.domain.com/ to https://subdomain.domain.com, we have included this in the htaccess file but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.domian\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// %1.domian.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: You have certificate for www.subdomain.domain.com or for subdomain.domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect everything https and www to the non-www equivalent:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```